# WHERE clause on calculated field not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access SQL query pulling back results from a Latitude & Longitude input (similar to a store locator). It works perfectly fine until I attempt to put in a WHERE clause limiting the results to only resultants within XXX miles (3 in my case).

The following query works fine without the `WHERE distCalc < 3` clause being added in:

```
PARAMETERS
  [selNum] Long
, [selCBSA] Long
, [cosRadSelLAT] IEEEDouble
, [radSelLONG] IEEEDouble
, [sinRadSelLAT] IEEEDouble;
SELECT B.* FROM (
  SELECT A.* FROM (
    SELECT
      CERT
    , RSSDHCR
    , NAMEFULL
    , BRNUM
    , NAMEBR
    , ADDRESBR
    , CITYBR
    , STALPBR
    , ZIPBR
    , simsLAT
    , simsLONG
    , DEPDOM
    , DEPSUMBR
    , 3959 * ArcCOS(
        cosRadSelLAT
      * cosRadSimsLAT
      * cos(radSimsLONG - radSelLONG)
      + sinRadSelLAT
      * sinRadSimsLAT
      ) AS distCalc  
    FROM aBRc
    WHERE CBSA = selCBSA
    AND cosRadSimsLAT IS NOT NULL
    AND UNINUMBR <> selNum 
  ) AS A
  ORDER BY distCalc
) AS B
WHERE B.distCalc < 3 
ORDER BY B.DEPSUMBR DESC;
```

When I add the `WHERE distCalc < 3` clause, I get the dreaded

> This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.

error.

Given that the value is created in the A sub-query I thought that it would be available in the outer B query for comparative calcs. I could recalculate the `distCalc` in the `WHERE`, however, I'm trying to avoid that since I'm using a custom function (`ArcCOS`). I'm already doing one hit on each row and there is significant overhead involved doing additional if I can avoid it.

Comment: Try moving that where clause up to right after the first derived table.  Also, your first order by clause is redundant.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The first order clause is a holdover when I was doing a Top 20 pull. While indeed unnecessary for the question I don't think it's causing the issue. Prior to writing the post I tried the WHERE distCalc < 3 clause in the first query and had the same result. I did just test it again and removed the outer query and had the same "too complex" error. To answer the 2nd question - I'm trying to pull records that are within 3 miles (calculated in the distCalc calc) of the passed parameters.

Comment: I've reformatted the query in case it helps. Also would recommend putting table alias qualifiers in front of the column names in the outer queries. Also, the middle subquery is not performing any function--you can just collapse the whole thing down to two levels.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it typed you are limiting it by B.distCalc, which is requires calcuation of A.distCalc, on which you are asking for a sort.  Even if this worked worked, would require n^2 calculations to compute.

Try putting the filter on distCalc in the inner query (using the formula for distCalc, not distCalc itself).

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why this would require n^2 calculations. I'll admit it's possible that Access implements this poorly, I really don't know, but other database systems would have no problem with this.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. Yes, I could do that, but I need the distCalc value so I'm back to 2 calculations. If I remove the WHERE distCalc < 3 and ORDER BY DEPSUMBR DESC and replace with an ORDER BY distCalc DESC it works. So I can sort on the calculation result on the outer query but cannot seems to filter (using WHERE) - this I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.  It's a formatted comment.  What happens when you do this:

```
select *
from (
select somefield, count(*) records
from sometable
group by somefield) temp
```

If that runs successfully, try it with

```
where records > 0
```

at the end.  If that fails, you probably need another approach.  If it succeeds, start building your real query using baby steps like this.  Test early and test often.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "solve" the problem by pushing the complicated formula into the function and then returning the value (which was then able to be used in the WHERE clause).

Instead of:

```
    3959 * ArcCOS( cosRadSelLAT * cosRadSimsLAT * cos(radSimsLONG - radSelLONG) + sinRadSelLAT * sinRadSimsLAT) AS distCalc
```

I went with:

```
    ArcCOS2(cosRadSelLAT,cosRadSimsLAT,radSimsLONG, radSelLONG,sinRadSelLAT,sinRadSimsLAT) AS distCalc
```

The ArcCOS2 Function contained the full formula. The upside is it works, the downside is that appears to be a slight tad slower. I appreciate everyone's help on this. Thank you.